# How do I create an object from a specific class and change its attributes by using methods in java

Tags: java, object, methods, attributes

```
public class Forklift{
    double height;
    Forklift fl_1, fl_2;
    
    Forklift(){
        fl_1 = new Forklift();
        fl_2 = new Forklift();
    }

    void raise(){
        height += 10;
    }
    void lower(){
        height -= 10;
    }
}
```

I'm currently using BlueJ. I want to create two objects with the attribute 'height' and I want to use the methods raise() and lower() to change the value of that attribute. Can someone please help me? I don't know why it's not working

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Do you know how to _call_ a method? Also you probably want to have a Main class to actually run the program.

Comment: Is it possible that you just want one Forklift, which has two forks? In that case you need another class `Fork` which has an attribute `height` and methods `raise()` and `lower()` and you need a class `Forklift` which has a attribute `leftFork` and `rightFork` which should be instances of `Fork`. What you are creating is basically an inifinite loop as you create a Forklift, and to create a forklift you have to create two forklifts which of their own require the creation of a forklift and so on...

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
public class Forklift{
    double height;
    
    Forklift(){
        height=0;
    }

    void raise(){
        height += 10;
    }
    void lower(){
        height -= 10;
    }
}
```

I dont understand why you are creating a forklift in the forklift constructor. That just gives you an infinite loop.

Edit: If you want to create two instances of the class, just use:

```
Forklift forklift1 = new Forklift();
Forklift forklift2 = new Forklift();
```

somewhere outside the class. Now you have two instances of the class.